# $gte and $lte with numberint isn't working correctly in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve documents which at least has one entry of **'cov.res.timestamp'** within some range.

```
{'cov.res.timestamp': {
        $gte: 1571424600,
        $lte: 1571597580
      }}
```

its listing the documents that doesn't fall under this range, what am I doing wrong here?

here is my sample document

```
"cov" : [
        {
            "order" : NumberInt(1), 
            "res" : {
                "text" : [
                    "Start the conversation!"
                ], 
                "source" : "watson", 
                "timestamp" : NumberInt(1566020214), 
                "timestamp_hr" : "17-08-2019 05:36:54"
            }
            "res":{},
            "res":{},
]
```

Comment: Can someone help me understand why simple range with $gte & $lte isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do but the condition is wrong by default mongodb and(s) the conditions so you either need $or or you made a type so here are the fixes option available:

```
{
  $or: [{
        'cov.res.timestamp': {
          $gte: 1571424600,
          $exists: true,
        },
        'cov.res.timestamp': {
            $lte: 1571597580,
            $exists: true,
          }
        }
      ]
  }
```

Or you need

```
{
     'cov.res.timestamp': {
        $lte: 1571424600,
        $gte: 1571597580
      }
}
```

Bhushan's answer is right I missed array somehow:

```
 db.xxxxx.aggregate(
    [
    // Stage 1
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$cov",
            includeArrayIndex : "arrayIndex", // optional
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false // optional
        }
    },
    // Stage 2
    {
        $match:{
            "cov.res.timestamp": {
                $gte:1571597580,
                $lte:1571424600
                }} 
    }
])
```

Comment: Hi @Black Mamba , Thanks for your reply, solution isn't working for me. I wanted to get all the documents if it has at least one **cov.res.timestamp** field within in the specified range(GTE & LTE) and I need logical AND condition there.

Comment: Did you try the first one? You cannot go for $and just think about what your code is doing how can some thing be greater than 10 and less then 1 as well. I think the first block should fix your issue.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, its listing document which doesn't have timestamps specified. but is it not applying both logics at the same time... I thought it would evaluate it as **a timestamp entry should be greater than and less than given values** which effectively is a range.

Comment: timestamp here is a unxtimestamp(18th Oct - 20th Oct), its listing a document which doesn't have timestamp in these dates. excuse me if I'm ignorant but I'm new to mongodb.

Comment: So you want between 18th-20th or you want before 18th and after 20th?

Comment: documents that has timestamp between Oct 18-20 dates.

Comment: Just try using the second one after `Or you need `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202327/discussion-between-epsan-and-black-mamba).

Answer (score 1):

Hi @epsan as u have mentioned that you want to display the whole document with the below condition satisfied for at least one element of the array **conv**

```
{'cov.res.timestamp': {
    $gte: 1571424600,
    $lte: 1571597580
  }}
```

as your trying to get data between 18-20 Oct 2019
**Tested by generating Dummy Data**
the Query is correct just cross check the other element **res**
to get only order matching condition I would recommend using aggregation.

```
    db.xxxxx.aggregate(
    [
    // Stage 1
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$cov",
            includeArrayIndex : "arrayIndex", // optional
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false // optional
        }
    },
    // Stage 2
    {
        $match:{
            "cov.res.timestamp": {
                $gte:1571424600,
                $lte:1571597580
                }} 
    }
    ])
```

Comment: this has worked to extract relevant documents, Thanks. but overall document count is bumped up, can i do something about it not to alter the json document format and no of documents?